# Android Kotlin Error getting App Check token using placeholder token instead. Error: com.google.firebase.FirebaseException: Too many attempts

Tags: kotlin, firebase-app-check, google-play-integrity-api

I am following this docs to integrate firebase AppCheck to my android app, and I saw an issue. Maybe because of `Too many attempts` my app is reached `out of quota` very soon. I tried to research, debug 3 days but could not find any solutions for this.

Integration Docs: https://firebase.google.com/docs/app-check/android/play-integrity-provider

```
override fun onCreate() {
    super.onCreate()

    Firebase.initialize(context = this)
    Firebase.appCheck.installAppCheckProviderFactory(
        PlayIntegrityAppCheckProviderFactory.getInstance(),
    )
}
```

Errors

```
2023-07-13 17:04:19.960 25147-25288 LocalRequestInterceptor xxxx.xxxx.xxxx                 W  Error getting App Check token; using placeholder token instead. Error: com.google.firebase.FirebaseException: Too many attempts.
2023-07-13 17:04:20.668 25147-25288 LocalRequestInterceptor xxxx.xxxx.xxxx                 W  Error getting App Check token; using placeholder token instead. Error: com.google.firebase.FirebaseException: Too many attempts.
2023-07-13 17:05:07.113 25147-25288 StorageUtil             xxxx.xxxx.xxxx                 W  Error getting App Check token; using placeholder token instead. Error: com.google.firebase.FirebaseException: Too many attempts.
2023-07-13 17:05:07.722 25147-25288 StorageUtil             xxxx.xxxx.xxxx                 W  Error getting App Check token; using placeholder token instead. Error: com.google.firebase.FirebaseException: Too many attempts.
2023-07-13 17:05:08.227 25147-25288 StorageUtil             xxxx.xxxx.xxxx                 W  Error getting App Check token; using placeholder token instead. Error: com.google.firebase.FirebaseException: Too many attempts.
```

I am using `Kotlin`, `Jetpack Compose` `Firebase`.

Of course, this error is happening in production. Not on debug mode.

Anybody can help?